# The word order of a comparative phrase seems strange

Tags: grammar, word-order, comparative-constructions, comparative

I have seen the following paragraph in some article:

> One can imagine a computer simulation of the action of peptides in the hypothalamus that is accurate down to the last synapse. But equally one can imagine a computer simulation of
> the oxidation of hydrocarbons in a car engine or the action of digestive processes in a stomach when it is digesting pizza. **And the simulation is no more the real thing in the case of the brain than it is in the case of the car or the stomach.**

I understand the meaning of the bold sentence, but I cannot understand its word order. For example, I think that the adverb "more" should be placed immediately before the adjective "real" and the sentence should be like the following:

- *And the simulation in the case of the brain is no more real than the simulation in the case of the car or the stomach.*

I wonder how the word order of the original sentence is justified.

Comment: The simulation is not 'what really happens in the brain' any more than the other simulations are what really happens in a car engine or the human stomach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[the real thing](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/real-thing?q=the%20real%20thing)** is a set phrase that is used regularly in everyday English. Note that, according to the Cambridge dictionary, it doesn't match any of the meanings of **[real](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/real)**. Here is their definition:

> the original, best, or most typical example of something

From the grammatical point of view, both are OK. A be-verb can be followed by a noun or an adjective, and inserting **no more** doesn't change that.

> This is **orange** - *adjective*
> This is the **book** - *noun*

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, in the sentence we have a comparative structure, "more ... than". We should not have an adjective after the adverb "more"?

Comment: More isn't just an adverb: according to the Cambridge Dictionary, it can be determiner, pronoun or adverb. It can also be used as a pre-determiner, as in your example, and in this sentence.  "She's no more a saint than I am." Lay Siege to Heaven, Louis de Whol, 1961. This construction is used in everyday conversation and in writing. https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/more